# changing template in Joomla after any customized theme

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am new to Joomla.Although i am very good in PHP.I got a source code of one joomla project with customised theme.but when i change this theme to any other existing default theme of joomla.It gave me a message that default theme successfully changed but it did not work on a site.Site keeps its old them.Can any body help me with this.

Comment: what about clearing Joomla cache if enabled, Check error logs too

Comment: no it does not concern with cache.

Answer (score 1):

Just to double check that the theme is default, go to phpMyAdmin and in the `#__template_styles` table, check if the default template has a number **1** in the **"home"** column.

If so, then your template has definitely been set as the default one. Go to your Joomla backend and on the top menu, go to **Site >> Maintenance >> Global Check-in**.

If this doesn't work I can only assume it's your cache.